# android connections problems with cc2540

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, rssi

I am developing a very simple App for a final year Degree project, It's a simple Proximity Application where once a Bluetooth device moves beyond the range, it creates a supervisor timeout which triggers an alarm.

My main problem is actually trying to make a connection with a TI CC2540  (KeyFob). I have loaded the demo software as provided by TI, all works well with Btool etc. and I am using a HTC Desire C (ICS, BT4.0), which does pair with the CC2540.  I have put together an APP, but have recently downloaded the BTChat Example from the Android SDK.  The Example App recognises the Keyfob, and even gets the correct Mac Address but as soon as I try to connect with it, it doesn't connect (Establish a Link).  I have carried out a lot of research and thought my problem may lie in the area of the UUID (128) but I am unable to find the correct UUID for the device.  Incidentally I have used the common one from the Android Dev Website, plus derivatives but with no success.

I eventually found an existing App for an Iphone (Bluetooth Smart Scanner) which did recognise my device but gave a 'null' response for the UUID.

I am at a loss about where to go, could anybody point me in the right direction?

best regards Wayne

Answer (score 0):

According to specification at [gsmarena](http://www.gsmarena.com/htc_desire_c-4759.php), the HTC Desire C may actually only have Bluetooth 3.0, so not 4.0 "low energy" (HTC's own website does not even mention bluetooth -- see [HTC website specs](http://www.htc.com/www/smartphones/htc-desire-c/#specs) ?). Android SDK does not support bluetooth low energy either... so you may be out of luck. There is somewhat supported Broadcom stack, and Motorola has their own stack... Samsung Galaxy S3 may be hacked to work by reverse engineering existing apps...

If you need a phone which does support Bluetooth LE, Motorola XT885 will do if you download the Motorola ICS_R2 Android SDK add-on. See this post: [Motorola BLE API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13272310/android-4-0-4-ble-api-broadcom-motorola)

Comment: Many thanks for the reply, from what I have read in the Bluetooth Low Energy book - Author Robin Heydon, that even BLE 4.0 devices connect using Classic Bluetooth, in my project I am only wishing to interrogate the RSSI and Battery level, fairly high level protocols, so even though my device is  BLE, it should still connect. It might need to receive a specific sting of data, but this is where i need the help.  I was advised initially to use Android over iOS, but from recent research an iphone 4, non BLE, can comunicate with a cc2540!! I will keep the site posted Best Regards wayne

Comment: hmmm..  From what I've read Bluetooth 4.0 has support for both LE and "regular" bluetooth.  However, devices don't need to support both modes and I'm pretty certain the cc2540 only supports LE (I'm doing work on one as well).  So, a device with only Bluetooth 3.0 would definitely not be able to connect to a cc2540.

Comment: BT Classic and BT LE are entirely incompatible. If you are seeing anything at all (as a result of receiving advertising) then your HTC must support BLE.  The CC254x are BLE only.